# Can't connect to SQL docker container (SSL rissues)

Tags: mysql, pandas, docker, sqlalchemy

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db_data:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: db_data
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_data
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - mainnetwork
```

When I try to run the following pandas commmand:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
data_reader = create_engine('mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/db_data?ssl=false')
df= pd.read_sql_table('reporting_data', con=data_reader)
```

I get the error:

```
OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol')
```

Comment: environment should be given using `VARIABLE=VALUE` format. and put dashes at the beginning

Comment: @mangusta I don't think that has nothign to do with the error, environment variables work fine

Comment: having browsed a bit, it seems that the valid one is `useSSL=false`, have you tried it instead?